# Publishing an MVC application using SQL Server Compact Edition to IIS

Tags: entity-framework, model-view-controller, sql-server-ce, code-first

I'm attempting to publish an MVC web application to a locally running instance of IIS using Visual Studio 2012. For the database, I'm running SQL Server Compact Edition and my connection string in the `web.config` looks like this:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="OpserveEntities" connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|Opserve.sdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
</connectionStrings>
```

When I follow through the Publish wizard, under Settings/Databases I'm entering `Data Source=|DataDirectory|Opserve.sdf`. When I attempt to publish I get the following error message:

> Unable to complete operation. The supplied SqlConnection does not specify an initial catalog or AttachDBFileName.

However, the application runs as expected when running/debugging in Visual Studio.

How can I resolve this and get my application published and working?

Comment: Here's the connection string which was missed in the initial question:

Comment: <connectionStrings>
    <add name="OpserveEntities" connectionString="Data Source=|DataDirectory|Opserve.sdf" providerName="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
  </connectionStrings>

Comment: Did you solve this problem? I can connect to a database when I publish it into the app_data folder, but I'm unable to 'create' the database and execute the migration scripts. Is it possible to use the SQL Server Compact for migration scripts or will this not work?